# Get GridViewRow from RadComboBox Event

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a **RadComboBox** column in a **Telerik RadGridView**, I want to do is that when you change item in the **RadComboBox**, disable **GridViewRow** where is the **RadComboBox**; for this I need to get the Parent of **RadComboBox** but what I tried does not work

This is my **RadGridView** code:

```
     <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dtgResumen" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" ShowGroupPanel="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" GridLinesVisibility="Both" >
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colStatus" Header="STATUS" Width="1.3*" >
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.HeaderCellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#538DD5" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.HeaderCellStyle>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox Name="comboBoxStatus" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Activa" Foreground="Green" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Cancelada" Foreground="Red" />
                                </telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
           </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

This is the code in the event:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var combo = sender as RadComboBox;

    var row = FindParent<GridViewRow>(combo);
}
```

This is the FindParent Code:

```
    public static Parent FindParent<Parent>(DependencyObject child) where Parent : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = child;

        //We are not dealing with Visual, so either we need to fnd parent or
        //get Visual to get parent from Parent Heirarchy.
        while (!((parentObject is System.Windows.Media.Visual) || (parentObject is System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D)))
        {
            if (parentObject is Parent || parentObject == null)
                return parentObject as Parent;
            else
                parentObject = (parentObject as FrameworkContentElement).Parent;
        }

        //We have not found parent yet , and we have now visual to work with.
        parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentObject);

        //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
        if (parentObject is Parent || parentObject == null)
            return parentObject as Parent;
        else
            //use recursion to proceed with next level
            return FindParent<Parent>(parentObject);
    }
```

I also tried with this but it did not work:

```
        var combo = sender as RadComboBox;
        var row = combo.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
```

Comment: Are you working in the code behind? If so can you access the DGV directly and access the CurrentRow or SelectedRows directly (this is assuming the when they are working on the combobox in the grid the row is selected)? this.dtgResumen.CurrentRow

Comment: @DavidOesterreich, the CurrentRow property does not exist